# Mysql query while inserting

Tags: mysql, database

After the Spark calculation, I got lots of data to insert to DB.

I'm just curious, should I always avoid querying the data while inserting? Will it cause something bad?

[image: my db]

However it seems to work well to me while inserting the data. Any tutorials will be helpful.

Comment: MYSQL / MariaDB is a multi user full DBMS. It can cope with multiple accesses with no problems

Comment: @RiggsFolly So technically it fetches the data(the data of the fetch command time), or it scans through rows and the scanning speed is faster than inserting speed and finally it stops and return? Thanks so much.